# Swift WCSession not reachable and counterpart app not installed (WatchConnectivity)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchos, watchconnectivity

I have an iOS app (MyApp) with a corresponding watch app (MyAppWatch). Using WatchConnectivity, I want to establish a connection between both device. Activating a WC session on both devices is succesful, but when testing the connection, something does wrong. It turns out that my **`session.isReachable` returns `false`**. Also, I get a message that **WCSession counterpart app not installed**. It may be interesting to add that *session.isPaired (on iOS) returns true*, so nothing seems to be wrong in the connection between the devices. I need isReachable to be true by *installing the counterpart app on the watch*, before being able to sendMessage(). But how? And why is this failing?

What I've tried so far:

- Removing the app on both devices
- Cleaning Build Folder
- Restarting XCode
- Adding MyAppWatch.app to the *Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content* of MyApp Target
- Enabling and disabling *Supports Runnings Without iOS App Installation* (MyAppWatch Target)
- All possible combinations of this

Can someone please help fixing this, I'm struggeling for days now.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using the simulators, one of the reasons why the *WCSession* might not be working is because you didn't pair the watch and the iPhone simulators.

If you go to *Window* > *Devices and Simulators* > *Simulators* it will let you also add a watch to each iPhone.

[image]
[image]

Call it a specific name so it's easy to find it.

You can also open both devices and go in the Watch app on the iPhone, so you can check that they are actually synced.

[image]

Usually when you run the app on that specific watch simulator it will automatically install the app also on the iPhone and it will say something like this:

[image]

This article covers some of the most common errors with connectivity (like *WCSession counterpart app not installed*), maybe it might help:
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-watchconnectivity-to-send-data-from-phone-to-watch-plus-most-common-errors-793d41976618